# Unwanted URL with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I created a custom post type. It's book and my url look like example.com/book/a-book I show books on example.com/books but there is example.com/book how can I delete that URL or show 404. In this case my sitemap shows that url: example.com/book

```
function book_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Books', 'Post Type General Name', 'sv' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Book', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'sv' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Books', 'sv' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Book', 'sv' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Books', 'sv' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Book', 'sv' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Book', 'sv' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'sv' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Book', 'sv' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Book', 'sv' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Books', 'sv' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'sv' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not Found In Trash', 'sv' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'books', 'sv' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Books', 'sv' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'revisions', ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => false,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'book_post_type', 0 );
```

Comment: nothing in your code here refers to books at all...

Comment: I edited it again. There is original code. When I try to connect example.com/book/ it redirects to another post. So It means there no page. But I am using Yoast SEO plugin. When I go to sitemap.xml which has posts of book. I see that URL in sitemap.

Comment: your code looks good.  can you try refreshing the yoast plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function rt_custom_post() {
  register_post_type( 'book',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Books' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Book' ), 
      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => false, //this will eliminate the archive page
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    'publicly_queryable'  => true
    )
  );
```

if you add :

```
'has_archive' => false,
```

to your register post type, it will remove the archive page.  Remember to flush the permalinks by visiting the settings -> permalinks page after you make the change.

Make sure you didn't create a page called book as well.

Comment: It works for 5 custom post types but there is one more I see it in sitemap.xml there is no page called like it and I flush the permalinks.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I edited my question